# R markdown knitr to html not showing results or tables

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am running a basic R markdown file and when I apply knitr and create a html page, Rstudio does not report the summary statistics of the data. I run the following;

````
xyz data
    ```{xyz}
    library(datasets)
    summary(airquality)
    ```
````

html

```
<pre class="summary"><code>summary(stock_returns_monthly)
summary(baseline_returns_monthly)
</code></pre>
<p>xyz data</p>
<pre class="xyz"><code>library(datasets)
summary(airquality)</code></pre>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nope, nothing, just prints the code and not the summary statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `xyz` for `r`

````
```{r}
library(datasets)
summary(airquality)
```
````

Comment: For some reason, I was thinking that was the title of the section like in html, `<h1>, <h2>...`